# update-motd.d scripts not running

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-14.04

I have created a test script below to add to /etc/update-motd.d/05-lsb-release

```
#!/bin/sh
echo
lsb_release -a
```

but when i have rebooted the machine, restarted SSH and connected to it through SSH i am not seeing the changes applied

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-105-generic x86_64)

0 packages can be updated. 0 updates are security updates. 

Last login: Sun Dec 11 17:08:40 2016 from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
paul@ubuntu1404:~$
```

the output in /var/run/update-motd.dynamic is the same as above, however /var/run/update-motd.dynamic.new shows the correct information

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-105-generic x86_64)

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.
```

how can i see the changes when i log in?

I am running the latest updates to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Answer (score 18):

You might have an error in your motd script. Check it with:

```
run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/ > /dev/null
```

Should this command report errors you need to fix them.

Comment: some (Ubuntu-authored) parts of the update-motd on my system required root, and don't forget to check your exit code! `echo $?` afterwards

Answer (score 6):

Test your motd like the (ubuntu? maybe debian too?) system does

`/usr/bin/env -i PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin run-parts --lsbsysinit /etc/update-motd.d`

(taken from this blog https://ownyourbits.com/2017/04/05/customize-your-motd-login-message-in-debian-and-ubuntu/)

in my case, lolcat was dying on utf8 chars because it was being launched with an ASCII as its language, fixed by prefixing the lolcal invocation with `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 lolcat ...`

Comment: This revealed my problem: `/usr/games/fortune` was on my `$PATH` in an interactive shell, nut not when `update-motd.d` was being run.

Comment: This revealed my problem: `/etc/update-motd.d/99-NewDisks` didn't match LSB namespaces. 22 years using Linux and it's the 1st time I hear about that !!!

Answer (score 4):

It is configured in the PAM. Have a look into the file `/etc/pam.d/sshd`. There is a line such as

```
session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate
```

which prevents dynamic updates when logging in (your "dynamic" MoTD is quite static, so it does not make sense to update it with every login, isn't it?).

More described in the [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833518/looking-to-specifically-customize-ubuntu-ssh-banner/833523#833523).

Comment: It is just a test to understand how dynamic motd works, afterwards I will be using different scripts

Comment: Can you please go into more detail to explain how one would update this?  I've read the AskUbuntu article and it does not clearly state how one would test the updated message.  **Edit** Ok, I found out what was happening. Adding a second answer as it was not immediately obvious and the AskUbuntu article -- although helpful -- was sending me down a rabbit hole.

Comment: Before checking `/etc/pam.d/sshd`, check that you have `UsePAM yes` in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: @dargaud every modern os has that.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For those on newer Ubuntu versions simply looking to update a static message, `/etc/motd.tail` is now `/etc/motd` (yes, you have to create this file), so for simple, static changes, the location has changed slightly between Ubuntu versions.  This file **will display when using `ssh` to remote into the machine**.

Use `sudo vi /etc/motd` and then paste this in...

```
 ^[[1;37m______ ______ ______ ______
|______|______|______|______|
| | ^[[1;31m____ ^[[1;33m     ^[[1;32m_  ^[[1;34m    ^[[1;36m     ^[[1;37m| |
| |^[[1;31m/ ___|^[[1;33m___ ^[[1;32m| | ^[[1;34m___  ^[[1;36m_ __^[[1;37m| |
| ^[[1;31m| |   ^[[1;33m/ _ \^[[1;32m| |^[[1;34m/ _ \^[[1;36m| '__|^[[1;37m |
| ^[[1;31m| |__^[[1;33m| (_) ^[[1;32m| ^[[1;34m| (_) ^[[1;36m| |  ^[[1;37m| |
| |^[[1;31m\____^[[1;33m\___/^[[1;32m|_|^[[1;34m\___/^[[1;36m|_|  ^[[1;37m| |
|_|____ ______ ______ ____|_|
|______|______|______|______|
^[[0m
```

Next, using `vi`, replace `^[` with the proper "escape" character (the `x1B` character).

- Within vi, press <kbd>:</kbd>
- Next type the following: `%s/\^\[/` (Do **NOT** hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
- Now type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> and then hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>
- Finally, type `/g` and finally hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- If done properly the `^[` changed from gray to blue.  If not, hit <kbd>u</kbd> to undo.
  What is this all doing?  Well...

  > `%s` (search)
  >   `/` (first item)
  >   `\^\[` (escaped version of `^[`)
  >   `/` (second item)
  >   (we use keyboard to insert actual `Esc`)
  >   `/g` (repeat for all occurrences)

**Note:** Despite the cosmetic weirdness, the blue `^[` characters are **completely valid `ESC` characters**, used to add color to the terminal. :)

If `vi` is too tough to use, `echo $'\e[1;37m' > myfile` can add the escape characters as well.  Furthemore, `gedit` can copy/paste these characters much better than `vi|nano`.

For more terminal colors, please visit https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174/190347

Comment: The file `/etc/motd/` does not exist anymore since Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: @JPelletier The answer never mentions `/etc/motd/` but I can see how that can be confusing.  Updated answer to make it more clear including screenshot.

Comment: It's just a typo, I meant `/etc/motd` because you were saying that in newer Ubuntu version it's the file to edit, but it's not the way to do it anymore since Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. All you have to remove/add/edit scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d`